# Looking at an array and changing it

Tags: java

I'm not allowed to use any imports such as Java.arrays/ArrayLists etc.

My code so far:

Comment: Your remove method does nothing, it's just returning the element corresponding to the argument index ! Since you are using simple array and aren't allowed to use list, you have to create a new array(skipping the element to delete), then replace your original array with the new one.

Comment: @Mooolo Okay I understand how I can copy an array over to a new one but how do I make it so it skips the element I don't want?

Comment: Where is your add method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that you never set the local variable `arrays` to `newArr`. Additionally, you do not finish creating `newArr`, as the return statement exits the method before the for loop completes. The correct code for the end of the remove method would be:

```
Object elementRemoved = null;
for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
    if(!deleteItem[i]){
        newArr[index++] = arrays[i];
    }
    else {
        elementRemoved = arrays[i];
    }
}
arrays = newArr;
return elementRemoved;
```

Note that this code will remove all instances of the object passed into the method.

Another correction: you are passing an index, but are comparing values. Also change the upper for loop so that you are comparing indices instead of values as such:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
    if(i == element){
        deleteItem[i]=true;
    }
    else{
        deleteItem[i]=false;
        size++;
    }
}
```

However, your indices in your testing method don't seem to be correct. If they're zero indexed, you would not get the results you claim. In fact, the 6th index would not exist after removing 2 elements (leaving behind only 6, with the greatest index being 5).

Comment: I changed my code around. The code nearly works

Comment: See my updated post. The indices you are telling it to delete won't exist on the third remove call. Remember, if the array is 0-indexed, the 6th item has an index of 5.